# css heart shape div does not appear the same when turned into a button

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have the following code

```css
.heart {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: red;
}

.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  content: '';
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.heart:before {
  bottom: 0px;
  left: -5px;
}

.heart:after {
  top: -5px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
```

However, I need this shape to become a submit button for a form. So I created a `button` instead with the same class name:

```
<button type="submit" class="heart"></button>
```

I'd assume that a button can still just look exactly the same. I've done some reading and noticed i need to have `border: none;` which I've added, but the shape is still not the same as it was when it was a `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the default `padding` and `border` of the button and you are good to go.

```css
.heart {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;  /*added code*/
  border: none;  /*added code*/
  outline:none;
}

.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  content: '';
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.heart:before {
  bottom: 0px;
  left: -5px;
}

.heart:after {
  top: -5px;
  right: 0px;
}
button.heart:active,
button.heart:active:after,
button.heart:active:before {
  background-color: #e80202;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #c50b0b;
}
```

```html
<div class=heart>
</div>


<button type="submit" class="heart"></button>
```

> **Note**: You can also change the style a little when is clicked by using
>   `:active` selector.

Comment: And that said, OP might want to look into something like [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Answer (score 0):

The button has default `padding` applied to it. Remove that in addition to the `border`:

```css
.heart {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  content: '';
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.heart:before {
  bottom: 0px;
  left: -5px;
}

.heart:after {
  top: -5px;
  right: 0px;
}

The html for this css is simply:
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="heart"></button><br><br>
<div class=heart>
</div>
```